# How to Implement Rest API Magento 2 for Mobile App

Tags: magento2

I read online tutorials for mobile app development.My question is this how I can implement those API in mobile which I will share with app developer.Does I need to add API in module and share module with App developer.Or just I need to share links for API format rest/V1/products etc.

Answer (score 0):

@Anees,
Magento2 already have REST API for all kind of calls like
product listing & management,

customer management

checkout & cart

you can check the API's with Swagger
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

or call swagger for your own setup
https://yourmagentowebsite.com/swagger

eg: https://magento2.demo.ubertheme.com/swagger

you can check this and create only the custom API's which are required.

you can check this to build your Android Mobile App.

https://github.com/st-sathish/magento2-android-native